# Downloading and saving file in a specific folder in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am writing a test where I need to download a csv file and then edit it and upload it.

As the first step I need to download it and save it in a specific folder where I have all my data

I have updated my config.ts file as below

```
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {

      prefs: {
          download: {
              'prompt_for_download': false,
              'directory_upgrade': true,
              'default_directory': './testdata/files/',
          }
      }
    }
  },
```

But it is not saving the file in the given path. It is saving in the default /Downloads folder. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use absolute path

```
        prefs: {
            'download.prompt_for_download': false,
            'directory_upgrade': true,
            'download.default_directory': path.resolve('./testdata/files/'), // <-----
        },
```